# How to know which query is resulting in errors in the trace?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trace

So, I got this:

[image]

A simple trace with `user errors`.

But, how can I know the query that has the problem listed here?

I don't think `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(X)` is appropriated to this.

EDIT 1:

Well, I'm using:

**STORED PROCEDURES:**

1. RPC: COMPLETED
2. RPC: STARTING
3. SP: COMPLETED
4. SP:STARTED

**TSQL:**

1. SQL:StmtCOMPLETED
2. SQL:StmtSTARTED

And I can see this now:

[image]

is there a better approach for this?

I could find the query, because it was the only statement using TOP.I think it was luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add the events `SQL:BatchStarting` and/or `SP:StmtStarting` as well. That way, you can compare the SPID (the session ID) and find which query executed on which SPID.

For the record, Profiler is being replaced by [Extended Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx) (XE for short) as of SQL Server 2008, though the GUI is really only usable as of 2012 in my opinion.